# Range of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Given that f : (0,1) → ℝ is continuous, what are the possible choices for its range f((0,1))?
Explain why your list exhausts all possible cases.

Comment: Since (0,1) is connected and f is continuous, using the IVT f((0,1)) should be connected as well.
Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(0,1)$ is connected, then the image $f((0, 1))$ (via continuous function) has to be connected as well. It can be shown that a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is one of the following:

$$(a,b), [a,b), (a,b], [a,b]\mbox{ where } a,b\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}\mbox{ wherever it makes sense}$$

Each of them is achievable. Here are some examples:

1. $(a,b)$ when $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$: $f(t)=(b-a)t+a$.
2. $(a,\infty)$ when $a\in\mathbb{R}$: $f(t)=\tan\big(t\frac{\pi}{2}\big)+a$
3. $(-\infty,\infty)=\mathbb{R}$: $f(t)=\tan\big((t+\frac{1}{2})\pi\big)$
4. [a,b) when $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$: $f(t)=(b-a)\big(\sin(-t\pi)+1\big) + a$
5. ...

Can you complete the list?